# Explode array into array in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array with ~ 10000 values.

Example:

```
  $arr = array("Name", "1.00", "87.70", "12.30",     
  "3.30", "3.30", "0.00", "3.50", "2.10", "1.11", "0.10", "14.00",
  "4.80", "0.00", "4.80", "0.00", "0.70", "44.00", "12.00", "85.00", 
  "138.00", "118.00", "0.10", "0.32", "1.00", "9.00", "40.00", "0.05", 
  "0.11", "0.04", "0.17", "0.10", "0.70", "5.00", "0.05", "0.40", 
  "1.00", "0.00", "65.00", "^_^", "Name2", "1.00", 
  "88.00", "12.00", "3.30", "3.30", "0.00", "3.20", "1.92", "1.01", 
  "0.08", "13.00", "4.80", "0.00", "4.80", "0.00", "0.70", "44.00", 
  "12.00", "85.00", "139.00", "118.00", "0.10", "0.32", "1.00", "9.00", 
  "36.00", "0.00", "0.10", "0.04", "0.17", "0.10", "0.70", "7.00", 
  "0.05", "0.40", "1.00", "0.00", "61.00", "^_^",
```

and so on....

I need to explode array when it reach value in array "^_^" and make array in array. And then I will and info into database.

I tried to explode, foreach and explode but didn't find a solution for this problem.

Comment: show us what you have tried. and tell us what is your expected output from this input?

Comment: I expect the output would be $arr[0][1] = "Name", $arr[0][2] = "1.0", $arr[1][1] = "Name2" and so on. With explode can't do this, because it retrieved error it expect a string. With foreach and explode don't work the way i want. So i searching for solution how can I solve this problem.

Comment: [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it first?

Comment: Thanks :) , I implode with ',', and then explode. It's working the way I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own function to do this. Here is a simple example that should explain it:

```
function array_split($arr, $splitBy) {
    $result = [];
    $subArray = [];

    foreach ($arr as $elem) {
        // If an element matches your delimiter,
        // add the current sub-array to the result set and start a new sub-array
        // Else add the element to the sub-array
        if ($elem == $splitBy) {
            $result[] = $subArray;
            $subArray = [];
        } else {
            $subArray[] = $elem;
        }
    }

    // Make sure the last sub-array also gets added to the result set
    $result[] = $subArray;

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_map
(
    function( $row )
    {
        return explode( ',', $row );
    },
    explode( ',^_^,', implode( ',',$arr ) )
);

print_r( $result );
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name
            [1] => 1.00
            (...)
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Name2
            [1] => 1.00
            (...)
        )
    (...)
)
```

Above code will works if the last element of original array is not `^_^`. Otherwise you have to modify the script in this way:

```
explode( ',^_^,', implode( ',', array_slice( $arr, 0, -1 ) ) )
#                               ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑     ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
```

You pass to [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) an array obtained by imploding original array with ',' and exploding resulting string by ',^_^,', then [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) returns each string exploded by ','.

---

- Read more about [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- Read more about [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
- Read more about [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- Read more about [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)